# Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run and Android app to Genymotion via `ionic run android` but i"m getting this:

```
Running command: /Users/luco/Desktop/lep/lep_prof/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/luco/Desktop/lep/lep_prof
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/luco/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
No target specified, deploying to device '192.168.56.102:5555'.
Error: spawn EACCES
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Android SDK folder permissions.